# How to configure ruby puts logs to show up in Java-JRuby log file

Tags: java, ruby, logging, jax-rs, jruby

I have configured JRuby within my JAX-RS application to run some ruby scripts. For debugging, I have used some "puts" statements in the ruby file. They are not getting logged in the JAX-RS webservice log file. How to configure?

Basically I want ruby "puts" logs to display in dropwizard webservice log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that I was able to use slf4j too

```
log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(self.class.name)
```

The logging level depends on what we set at the root level in config.yaml. Only if that is set to DEBUG, we can see log.debug entries.

```
logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: DEBUG
```

I also noticed configuring log level at the package/class level, does not log “debug” statements from ruby

```
loggers:
  # Sets the level for 'com.example.app' to DEBUG.
  com.example.test: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

Since jruby-complete dependency is brining in apache-commons-logging jar, I used the following statements in the ruby script and it logged it to the configured webservice log

```
age = 10
log = org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(self.class.name)
log.info("hello from ruby " + age.to_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This page describes how to override puts in ruby with new behavior

[Ruby: overriding the puts method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463873/ruby-overriding-the-puts-method)

You can then use org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger , org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog (etc) from inside the overridden function.

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything new to the existing answers. Can you provide a complete example?