# In Ruby, which is the object where the method puts is applied?

Tags: ruby

In ruby you use the dot to call a method, or in other words, to send a method to the object treated.

```
"100".to_i
```

We are sending to the object "100" the message to_i

When we do:

```
puts "hello"
```

The method puts, to which object is applied?

I thought this:

```
self.puts "hello"
```

Where self would be main, like the environment where you are now, the irb console for example.

But it throws an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):17
NoMethodError (private method `puts' called for main:Object)
```

Why is this wrong? Where is the method puts applied?

**UPDATE:** Ruby 2.7 allows calling private methods with self. This feature was requested and discussed at [1](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16123) and [2](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11297).

Comment: You say that "it throws an error". Did you read the error? What does the error tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP is correct in thinking that, when the explicit receiver is omitted, the receiver becomes `self`. And since `puts` works without an explicit receiver, it is not that bad of an idea to try `self.puts "hello"` in the same environment. Indeed `puts` is defined on `main`, or whatever object `self` points to in the given environment.

The issue here is that the methods that can be called with an explicit receiver are *public* methods, whereas the method `puts` is a *private* method, which rejects explicit receivers.

A standard way to detour this restriction is to use the method `send` as follows:

```
self.send(:puts, "hello")
```

Comment: Ah! I had wondered if Ruby made an exception for Kernel methods, but that would be un-Ruby like. This explains why Kernel is included in Object. An interesting test is to add a private method to Kernel to inspect the receiver like `module Kernel private def whoami self.class; end; end; p whoami()`

Comment: @Schwern If you want to see where `puts` is defined, you can simply do `method(:puts).owner # => Kernel`.

Comment: Yeah, it was clear where it was defined. It wasn't clear to me who the receiver was or how a private method was being called. Though it's still not clear to me how `self` is an instance of Object outside a method definition. Usually it's an instance of Class. Just a special case?

Comment: @Schwern Yes, it is a special case. The in the main environment, `self` is the object called `main`.

Comment: It is only instance of `Class` inside `class...end`. It is instance of `Module` instance of `module...end`. It is instance of whatever the method is being defined on inside `def...end`. Outside everything, it is `main`. It's not an exception, really - it's just that there's very few times anyone tries explicitly to examine `self` outside any of the abovementioned blocks.

Answer (score 5):

[`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) is a module method of [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html). `Kernel` is included by `Object` so it's available from nearly every class. `puts "foo"` and `Kernel.puts "foo"` are equivalent. The difference is `Kernel.puts` is explicit while `puts` could call a locally defined `puts` method.

```
def puts(str)
  p "my puts: #{str}"
end

puts "foo";        # "my puts: foo"
Kernel.puts "foo"  # foo
```

Under the hood, `Kernel.puts` calls [`$stdout.puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html). `$stdout` is a predefined global instance of [`IO`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, when you leave out the receiver of a message send, then the implicit receiver is *always* `self`. (No exceptions.)

So, saying

```
foo
```

where `foo` is not a local variable in the current lexical scope, is *always* equivalent to

```
self.foo
```

However, there is a small wrinkle: in Ruby, the definition of a `private` method is "a method than can only be invoked as the result of a message send without a receiver". So, while `foo` and `self.foo` are equivalent in terms of the receiver of the message send, there may be differences with access control. In particular, if `foo` is `private`, then `foo` will work but `self.foo` will `raise` a `NoMethodError` exception with the message (for example) `` NoMethodError (private method `foo' called for main:Object) ``.

So, you were right all along:

```
puts
```

is equivalent to

```
self.puts
```

but you misread the error message: it's no that the method doesn't exist, it's that the method is `private`.

In particular, all of those methods that are intended to be more like "procedures" in that they don't actually do anything interesting with their receiver, are defined in `Kernel` and are defined as `private` methods. This also includes methods like `Kernel#print`, `Kernel#require`, etc.