# how to monkey patch the puts method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to wrap the `puts` method with new lines before and after.

I searched the docs and didn't find where this function comes from. Ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463873/ruby-overriding-the-puts-method

Comment: You could as well just wrap the `puts` method inside another method. If only thing you want to achieve is new lines before and after the `puts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `puts` method like so:

```rb
def puts(object)
  super('')
  super(object)
  super('')
end
```

If you really wanted to you could monkey patch the method like below. Although your changes would probably have unintended effects.

```rb
module Kernel
  def puts(object)
    # code
  end
end
```

You can read about monkey patching in the Ruby docs [here](http:///https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).